# Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED in running android app of react native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to run my react native application on an android emulator. It runs for some time then gives me the error that `Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted`.
This is the actual error that I get -

```
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/auth' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v7.2.1 but found v7.3.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
792 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 790 up-to-date
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 20s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this as well. The solution I used is now in the docs [here](https://rnfirebase.io/#increasing-android-build-memory).

You might also want to pin your npm package versions in your package.json for the react-native-firebase packages to make sure the right version are installed (you may need to remove your yarn.lock file first).

Comment: Hi so that error was eliminated but now, I got the error `Native module RNGoogleSignin tried to override RNGoogleSigninModule error`. But the thing is that I have just downloaded the npm package and done the installation for ios. How do I go about solving this problem?