# React Native Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to install react-native-async-storage/async-storage to my project but I can't. I tried to install with yarn but I got Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'. error and I can't install with npm.

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED in running android app of react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639237/task-appmergeextdexdebug-failed-in-running-android-app-of-react-native)